# How do I specify pluralizeTableNames in Castle Active Record Integration?

Tags: .net, castle-activerecord

I used a section in my app.settings to configure AR, in which I specified:

```
<activerecord pluralizeTableNames="true">
```

Now, I moved to using ActiveRecordIntegration facility and a separate xml file. How can I configure pluralizeTableNames ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just put the attribute in the facility declaration:

```
<facility id="arfacility" pluralizeTableNames="true" ...>
 ...
</facility>
```